# Is it possible to use a .bat file to turn off 'Input indicator' when Windows starts?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, language-bar

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-language-bar-windows 
I am using Windows 10 and have done the following according to the above instructions.

'Use the desktop language bar when it's available' has been disabled in 'Advanced settings'.
'Language Bar' has been set to 'Hidden' in 'Text Services and Input Languages'.
'Input indicator' has been turned off in 'Turn system icons on or off'.

However, 'Input indicator' turns itself back on after every reboot.
Is it possible to use a .bat file to turn it off when Windows starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all but one language from your keyboard entry options.

Go to your Control Panel, go to the Languages option (I'm on mobile, can't remember the exact name right now). Remove all the keyboard layouts except the one you want to keep. When you hit OK, the Language bar disappears!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to remove all but one language from my keyboard entry options because I use sometimes Chinese and sometimes English. 
Is there another solution?